# error when executing same loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new to Python and I really want to understand why I get this error.

It happens in my `findLargest` function, while trying to execute the second `for` loop. The thing is that the second `for` loop does basically the same thing as the first one, but for some reason I get an error as I try to call on a `(class)method`. How can this be? Am I not allowed to have 2 for loops for same iterable in the same function?

```
shapeArea=shape.area()
```

throws:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

The objective of `findlargest()` is to loop through the set of classes twice, first in order to find the largest `value(Area)` while the second tries to find if there are other values that are equal.

```
class Shape(object):

    def area(self):
        raise AttributeException("Subclasses should override this method.")


class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, base, height):
        self.base = base
        self.height = height
    def area(self):
        self.area = (self.base * self.height) / 2
        return self.area
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} with base {} and height {}".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.base, self.height)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(other) == Triangle and self.base == other.base and self.height == other.height

class ShapeSet:

    def __init__(self):
        self.shape_list = []

    def addShape(self, sh):

        if sh not in self.shape_list:
            self.shape_list.append(sh)

        else:
            print ("{} is already existing".format(sh.__str__())) 

    def __iter__(self):
        return (self.shape_list)     

    def __str__(self):
        s = ''
        for shape in self.__iter__():
            s+= shape.__str__() + "\n"
        return s

ss = ShapeSet()
ss.addShape(Triangle(1.2,2.5))
ss.addShape(Triangle(1.4,2.5))
ss.addShape(Triangle(1.3,2.5))
ss.addShape(Triangle(1.5,2.5))

def findLargest(shapes):
    maxs = None
    maxA = 0.0
    for shape in shapes.__iter__():
        shapeArea = shape.area()
        if shapeArea > maxA or maxs == None:
            maxs = shape
            maxA = shapeArea
    maxTuple = (maxs)
    for shape in shapes.__iter__():
        shapeArea = shape.area()
```

Comment: You don't declare `shapes`, only `ss`. `shapes` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
def area(self):
    self.area=(self.base*self.height)/2
    return self.area
```

You enter the method and then immediately mask it by assigning a different name to its reference. From then on, `self.area` refers to that number and you can no longer access that method. Fortunately, the fix is easy: don't save a reference at all.

```
def area(self):
    return self.base * self.height / 2
```

Python does not separate the names for function/method objects and for other objects. Use unique reference names for any objects you'd like to retain.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
class Triangle(Shape):
def __init__(self, base, height):
    self.base=base
    self.height=height
def area(self):
    self.area=(self.base*self.height)/2 ###################### HERE
    return self.area
```

If you have

```
shape = Triangle(1.5,2.5)
shape.area() # returns float assigned at "HERE" to shape.area
shape.area() # try to call that float assigned in previous step at "HERE"
```